# Temporarily disable button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to disable a button element without removing the listener, for example I have ths following code:

```
<input id="in" />
<button id="sub">Submit</button>

$('#sub').click(function (e) {
    //Some actions
});


$($('#in').keyup(function (e) {
    if (new Date($(this).val()) == 'Invalid Date') {
        $(this).addClass('invalid');
        $('#sub').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('invalid');
        $('#sub').removeClass('disabled');

    }
});
```

I would like to unbind the button click listener, but if I'll use `off()` or `unbind()` I will have to 're-bind' it in the `else` clause.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: You don't want to unbind actions right? So you can use the disabled property like $("#sub").prop("disabled",true);

Comment: is there a reason why you dont want to attach the event in the else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about disabling the button instead of adding a class?

**HTML:**

```
<button>Disable Me</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        alert("click!");
       $(this).prop("disabled", true); 
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
button[disabled] {
 color: red;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/rV4nz/1/) is a jsFiddle to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

use `$('#sub').prop('disabled');`