# How to disable a button if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I disable a button by clicking a certain button?

It looks like this, if I click the Accept button (Accept button only is disabled) other button is enabled. `order_status = Accepted` then `submitAccept` button will be disabled.

But what is happening right now is it didn't get the value of order_status (Accepted) even if I change it in dispatched the submitAccept button is still disabled.

UPDATE: It disable button accept BUT it disable ALL accept button even the order_status is dispatched or pending
Heres my code

```
<?php 


 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="order_status" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order Status</label> 
 <div class="col-lg-3">
 <input type="text" input style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="order_status" id="order_status" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly>
 </div> 
 </div>

  <?php 
  if(isset($_POST['ORDER_ID'])){  
$order_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['ORDER_ID']));
$sql = "SELECT food_name, special_request, quantity, amount 
FROM cart_tbl
WHERE order_id=$order_id";
$result = mysqli_query(connection2(), $sql);}
?>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
 <thead>
 <tr> 
 <th>Food</th>
 <th>Special Request</th>
 <th>Quantity</th>
 <th>Amount</th> 
 </tr>
 </thead> 
 <?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["food_name"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["special_request"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["quantity"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["amount"];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>

</table>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" input style="background-color:##FF0000;color:white;float:left" name="showFood" id="showFood" class="btn btn-primary " onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to see food order?')){return false;}" > Show Food</button>
<button type="submit" input style="background-color:#4CAF50;color:white" name="submitDelivered" id="submitDelivered" class="btn btn-primary " onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to deliver order?')){return false;}" > Delivered </button>
// HERE IT IS\\ <button type="submit" input style="background-color:#0000FF;color:white" name="submitAccept" id="submitAccept" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to accept order?')){return false;}" <?php if($_POST['$order_status']="Accepted"): ?> disabled <?php endif ?> > Accept </button>
 <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myDropdown"> Send </button> 
 <button type="submit" input style="background-color:#f44336;color:white" name="submitCancel" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel order?')){return false;}">Cancel</button> 
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['submitDelivered'])){  
  $order_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['ORDER_ID']));
  $driver_number= trim(addslashes($_POST['drivers_number']));
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Delivered' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
  if (mysqli_query(connection2(), $query)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "COMMIT");
         $_SESSION['message'] = "Order Delivered"; } 
         else { 
         $_SESSION['message'] = mysqli_error(connection2());
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "ROLLBACK");
         }

  if($_POST['drivers_number']!=0){      
  $query2 = "UPDATE driver_tbl SET `order_id`='' WHERE `driver_number` = $driver_number";
  if (mysqli_query(connection2(), $query2)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "COMMIT");
         }
    }
  }

  if(isset($_POST['submitAccept'])){  
  $order_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['ORDER_ID']));
  $driver_number= trim(addslashes($_POST['drivers_number']));
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Accepted' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
  if (mysqli_query(connection2(), $query)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "COMMIT");
         $_SESSION['message'] = "Order Accepted"; } 
         else { 
         $_SESSION['message'] = mysqli_error(connection2());
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "ROLLBACK");
         }

  if($_POST['drivers_number']!=0){      
  $query2 = "UPDATE driver_tbl SET `order_id`='' WHERE `driver_number` = $driver_number";
  if (mysqli_query(connection2(), $query2)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "COMMIT");
         }
    }
  }


  if(isset($_POST['submitCancel'])){  
  $order_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['ORDER_ID']));
  $driver_number= trim(addslashes($_POST['drivers_number']));
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Cancelled' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
  if (mysqli_query(connection2(), $query)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "COMMIT");
         $_SESSION['message'] = "Order Cancelled"; } 
         else { 
         $_SESSION['message'] = mysqli_error(connection2());
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "ROLLBACK");
         }

  if($_POST['drivers_number']!=0){      
  $query2 = "UPDATE driver_tbl SET `order_id`='' WHERE `driver_number` = $driver_number";
  if (mysqli_query(connection2(), $query2)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "COMMIT");
         }

    }
  }

  ?>

 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I also tried this code but nothings happen.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function () {
      ($order_status).keyup(function (){
          if ($order_status == 'Accepted') {
              ('.submitAccept').prop('disabled',true);
          }else{
              ('.submitAccept').prop('disabled', false);
          }
  })
  };
  );

  </script>
```

Comment: well you got an error in your JavaScript code

Comment: @espascarello oh really? whats wrong in my JS dude?

Comment: The web developer console should have an error. Where is `$order_status` defined?

Comment: @epascarello In my textbox

Comment: I see no `var $order_status = ....`

Comment: `$order_status` is not defined in the javascript.  You're missing `var $order_status = $("#order_status")`.  You might like to stop using hungarian notation for your variables, or at least use a different one for php vs jquery.

Comment: @epascarello But I called the textbox, so it doesn't need a variable to hold the value...

Comment: Dude, You are wrong. id="order_status" does NOT magically bind to `$order_status`. Next if you use just `order_status` without the $ it still would not work since there is no keyup method on a DOM. Next thing after that $order_status is not going to magically also hold a string value and also be a reference to the element.

Comment: It doesn't *need* a variable, correct.  But you *are using a variable*, it's just not defined.  You could use `$("#order_status").keyup...`

Comment: You might like to have a read of [mcve] and create a **minimal** snippet that reproduces your specific problem - ie without all of the php hieroglyphs.

Comment: @freedomn-m Bro can you rewrite the whole code of your answer? So I can understand it more clearly.

Comment: It would look exactly the same as @Himan 's answer already provided.

Comment: @freedomn-m so where i should put the variable? var $order_status = $("#order_status").keyup(function (){.... there?

Comment: This has nothing to do with server sided scripting, will be removing the tag

Comment: @DarylGill what do you mean bro?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Temporarily disable button using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186147/temporarily-disable-button-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code is not correct. I am also not sure how order_status value is being populated, since its a `readonly` field.

```
 $(function () {
  ($("#order_status").keyup(function (){
      if ($("#order_status").val() == 'Accepted') {
          ('.submitAccept').prop('disabled',true);
      }else{
          ('.submitAccept').prop('disabled', false);
      }
  })
 };
);
```

Comment: Does user has to type in value for order_status?

Answer (score 0):

The code contains multiple errors, including HTML errors, for example:

```
<input type="text" input style="width:500px" 
class="form-control" name="order_status" 
id="order_status" placeholder="" value="" 
required="required" readonly>
```

To specify that "order_status" is the name of an input, you need only code "input" once instead of twice in the input tag.

The JavaScript also needs correction. To refer to the HTML element "order_status", in jQuery the correct syntax is $("#order_status"). And, there is another element "sumbitAccept" which in jQuery you refer to as `$("#submitAccept").` I also added some code to update the readonly input.

```js
function doAccepted() {
  $('#order_status').val('Accepted');
  $('#submitAccept').prop('disabled',true).css({"background-color":"#ccc"});
  if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to accept order?')){
   $('#order_status').val('Accepted').val("");
  $('#submitAccept').prop('disabled',false).css({"background-color":"#00f"});
  return false;
  } 
  else 
  {
       return true;
  }    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="submit" style="background-color:#0000FF;color:white" name="submitAccept" id="submitAccept" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="doAccepted()"> Accept </button>

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="order_status" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order Status</label> 
 <div class="col-lg-3">
 <input type="text"  style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="order_status"  id="order_status" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly>
 </div> 
 </div>
```

```
// error in the PHP:  
<?php 
 if($_POST['$order_status']="Accepted"): ?> disabled <?php endif ?> > 
 Accept </button>
```

Replace the "=" with "==" in order to do a test for equality -- that's a common error and one you can avoid if you rewrite code following this kind of format:

```
<?php if("Accepted" == $_POST['$order_status']): ?>
```

That said the PHP is a problem waiting to happen.  You must always consider submitted form values as tainted and validate and/or filter them *before using them* in your code.

Lastly, just because you make a form element readonly doesn't mean that it's safe.  Anyone with malevolent intent could spoof that form and remove the readonly property and submit the form.

One more thing, although PHP rode on a wave of popularity originally because you could embed PHP in HTML code, that's not necessarily the best idea.  It is much better to have a separation of concerns following the model-view-controller model aka MVC. You'll find it easier to debug, your code and your architecture will be more robust.

Comment: Why it need to update the readonly bro? If it automatically update whenever I click a button. What your code doing bro is it disabled ALL button for ACCEPT even the order_status is dispatched or pending. And it set ALL the order_status to Accepted.

Comment: @OnePunch  I've amended the code based on my best understanding of your comment which may or may not be correct, but I  hope that this may work better for you.